# Help understanding reciprocal polynomial of even degree

Tags: polynomials

I have difficulty understanding the IIIrd point from my textbook(Grewal - Higher Engg Math). Clearly $x^2+x-1=0$ satisfies the requirement of `even degree` and `coefficients`. But $1,-1$ are not its roots. I feel I'm missing something simple here.. What exactly is my textbook trying to say?
[image]

Answer (score 1):

This polynomial is not reciprocal? Try substituting in $1/x$ for $x$.

Comment: I see my error now.. Thank you so much James :)

Comment: Easy mistake to make!

Answer (score 1):

The reverse polynomial to $$x^2+x-1$$ is $$-x^2+x+1,$$ and multiplied with $-1$ also $$x^2-x-1,$$ which both are not the same as the original. As the assumption is violated, the claim need not be satisfied.

For the even degree polynomials the word "unchanged" needs to have an extended meaning, as a negation of the result appears admissible in III. Examples of reciprocal polynomials of degree $2$ are $x^2+3x+1$ and $x^2-1$.

Comment: Oh I see.. $$x^4 +8x^3 -8x-1=0$$ satisfies III and does have $-1, 1$ as its roots. I get it Thank you so much!

Comment: It seems an even degree polynomial with opposite coefficients `can not` be reciprocal if it has all the terms($x^2$ term is not allowed in example above).

Comment: Yes, the coefficient of the middle term would have to be equal to its negative, which is only possible for $0$.